# Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, port, localhost

I have running **nginx** server (doesn't matter which server):

`$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 80`

```
  tcp     0      0 0.0.0.0:80   0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      4268/nginx      
  tcp6    0      0 :::80        :::*              LISTEN      4268/nginx
```

And then I sent request to 127.0.0.1

`$ curl -v 127.0.0.1`

```
* Rebuilt URL to: 127.0.0.1/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

`$ telnet localhost 80`

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

All right in **/etc/hosts**:

```
127.0.1.1   ubuntu-work
127.0.0.1   localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts 
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**iptables** disabled `$ sudo iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

It's interesting that I can connect to any address 127.*.*.* except 127.0.0.1 (localhost). And also I can connect with my subnet ip-address 10.0.2.15.
And If I change port 80 to another in server config (e.g. Listen 88) it works.

I tried `$ sudo nmap -sS 127.0.0.1 -p 80` and got info - **80/tcp closed**, but how it's possible if running nginx server on port 80?

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00011s latency).
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp closed http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.12 seconds
```

**loopback interface is up:** `$ ifconfig`

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:86:5f:e3  
      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe86:5fe3/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:588 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:616 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:262986 (262.9 KB)  TX bytes:103011 (103.0 KB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:276 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:276 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:32750 (32.7 KB)  TX bytes:32750 (32.7 KB)
```

**Other iptables tables**

Output of `$ sudo iptables -t nat -nvL`:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 40 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 20559
0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 redir ports 20558

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 40 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1043 packets, 65731 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 20559
0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1            tcp dpt:443 redir ports 20558

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1043 packets, 65731 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I didn't get any output of `sudo iptables -t mangle -nVL`, only version: `iptables v1.4.21`

Output of `sudo iptables -t mangle -nL`

```
   Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination         

   Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination         

   Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination         

   Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination         

   Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination
```

Please help me if you have any ideas about what blocking localhost:80.

Comment: your loopback interfaces is up?

Comment: c4f4t0r, yes it's up, I added ifconfig output above.

Comment: Output for the other `iptables` tables, please (i.e. `iptables -t nat -nvL` and `iptables -t mangle -nVL`)

Answer (score 12):

Nothing is blocking port 80. You just have firewall NAT rules which are redirecting connections to that port to other ports, which aren't open.

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 40 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 20559
0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 redir ports 20558

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1043 packets, 65731 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 20559
0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1            tcp dpt:443 redir ports 20558
```

Remove these rules to resolve the problem.

Comment: How to remove rules?

Comment: `sudo iptables --flush`